# why Finalize method not available to custom types

Tags: c#, garbage-collection

Since Finalize() is defined protected in Object and everything is derived from Object. why Finalize(), unlike Equal() and ToString(), is not available for (derived) custom types to call directly in C#? I am not saying it should be called but just wonder why it's unavailable.

Comment: The C# compiler intentionally hides it.  You are supposed to use the "destructor", `~CustomClass`.

Comment: And better not to use it at all if possible.

Comment: Here is [a very good article](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/29365) explaining the why and how of finializers in C#.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To simply expand what @HansPassant means, let's check one example.

`System.IO.FileStream` defines a finalizer, (I use ILSpy to decompile the code),

```
// System.IO.FileStream
~FileStream()
{
    if (this._handle != null)
    {
        this.Dispose(false);
    }
}
```

OK, now in ILSpy let's switch the language from C# to IL,

```
.method family hidebysig virtual 
    instance void Finalize () cil managed 
{
    // Method begins at RVA 0xb4154
    // Code size 25 (0x19)
    .maxstack 2

    .try
    {
        IL_0000: ldarg.0
        IL_0001: ldfld class Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles.SafeFileHandle System.IO.FileStream::_handle
        IL_0006: brfalse.s IL_000f

        IL_0008: ldarg.0
        IL_0009: ldc.i4.0
        IL_000a: callvirt instance void System.IO.Stream::Dispose(bool)

        IL_000f: leave.s IL_0018
    } // end .try
    finally
    {
        IL_0011: ldarg.0
        IL_0012: call instance void System.Object::Finalize()
        IL_0017: endfinally
    } // end handler

    IL_0018: ret
} // end of method FileStream::Finalize
```

Do you get it now? When a finalizer is defined in C#, the C# compiler translates it to a function that override `System.Object.Finalize`. Thus, for this `Finalize` method alone, the only way to override it in C#, is to define a finalizer.

Comment: Ok it's clear that it's not possible to override finalizer but has to define one. So to the real part of my question, I am guessing the reason why compiler doesn't allow, from a syntax point of view, someting like baseClass.Finalizer() is because it's defined as virtual in Object so it would be meaningless to call base class implementation of Finalizer(). And it's another way of "forcing" to define own finalizer? Thanks.

Comment: Yes. The compiler cannot afford `Finalize()` to be overridden twice :)

Answer (score -1):

MSDN documentation is very confused in this topic.

> You should override Finalize for a class that uses unmanaged resources such as file handles or database connections that must be released when the managed object that uses them is discarded during garbage collection.

On the other hand (and this is important):

> The C# compiler does not allow you to override the Finalize method. Instead, you provide a finalizer by implementing a destructor for your class.

I think that Finalize() is defined for basic types because of carbage collection. Destructor has the same purpose, really.